# Excel: Search Series of Values from Large Table

Tags: excel

I have a large Excel table (with circa 9133 rows) which contains 4 columns. On a separate column, i have a series of values (300 cells to be exact) which i wanna search on the larger table and return the rows which have those values in the first column. What is the simplest way to achieve this instead of applying the filter and having to select the values manually?

Comment: You could probably use an Advanced Filter.

Comment: Couldn't you quickly do a vlookup?

Comment: What do you want to further achieve after getting the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP` to get this. Assuming your original list is in A2:D9134
and your shorter list is in G1:G300,

in the next column write

```
=VLOOKUP(G1, $A$2:$D$9134, 2, false)
```

in subsequent columns,use the same formula,but change 2 to 3 or 4.

You should get all the results.

If you want to show blanks where no match is found, use `IFERROR()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `INDEX, MATCH` formula.

```
=INDEX($B$3:$E$7,MATCH($G3,$B$3:$B$7,0),COLUMNS($B$3:C$3))
```

[image]

As screenshot enter formula in `H3` cell and drag and drop both down and right.